# How to display type alias in function description instead of all properties when extending an interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellisense

Using Typescript, is it possible to "hide" some properties under a type alias for more readable mouseover description?

I'm building a react component extending the html button element and adding some custom properties, however the mouseover description tries to show all 200+ valid properties and it's not the best experience.

Ideally i would like my custom properties to be highlighted, and display the html button attributes under a type alias for readability

My code :
`

```
interface ButtonBase extends Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"button">, "children"> {
    block?: boolean;
    label?: string;
    icon?: IconOptions | JSX.Element;
    iconDisposition?: "none" | "left" | "right" | "icon-only";
}
type Intention = "primary" | "secondary" | "danger";
interface ButtonContained extends ButtonBase {
    variant?: "contained";
    intention?: Intention;
}
interface ButtonOutlined extends ButtonBase {
    variant: "outlined";
    intention?: Intention;
}
interface ButtonInvisible extends ButtonBase {
    variant: "invisible";
    intention?: Extract<Intention, "primary">;
}
type ButtonProps = ButtonContained | ButtonOutlined | ButtonInvisible;

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>...
```

`

The mouseover description when using the component:

`(alias) const Button: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<(Pick<ButtonContained, "variant" | "form" | "label" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "key" | "autoFocus" | "disabled" | "formAction" | "formEncType" | "formMethod" | ... 261 more ... | "iconDisposition"> | Pick<...> | Pick<...>) & React.RefAttributes<...>> import ButtonComponent`

What I would like to achieve for the mouseover description:

`(alias) const Button: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<my custom properties & htmlAttributesAlias & React.RefAttributes<...>> import ButtonComponent`

Help much appreciated !

Comment: Related TypeScript feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56010.